# Add items to Future[List] inside recursion

Tags: scala, recursion, scala-collections

I'm having an issue with Future  List inside a recursion.

When i implemented this method without Futures  i used  **ListBuffer** and then adding items to the list.

```
    val filtered = ListBuffer.empty[PostMD]
    filtered ++= postMd.filter(_.fromID == userID)
```

Now i'm trying to implement it with Futures but i can't find a similar solution
What will be the best way to work with a Future List.

```
 def getData(url: String, userID: String) = {

val filtered: (List[PostMD]) => Future[List[PostMD]] = Future[List[PostMD]]

def inner(url: String): Unit = {

  val chunk: Future[JsValue]  = BusinessLogic.Methods.getJsonValue(url)

  val postMd: Future[List[PostMD]] = for {
    x <- chunk.map(_.\("data").as[List[JsValue]])
    y <- x.map(_.\("data").as[PostMD])
  } yield y


  filtered = postMd.map(_.filter(_.fromID == userID))   // <- returned  Future[List[PostMD]]

  val next: String = (chunk.map(_.\("paging").\("next"))).toString

 if (next != null) inner(next)
}
inner(url)
filtered

 }
```

thanks,

miki

Comment: Can you share a sample of the JSON? Also, it looks like you're using play-json. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes im using play-Json and play-WS in order to get the data.
Im assuming that their more ways to do that...
the json is facebook api json
this is an exemple http://pastebin.com/2MM88AJT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to do what you want with random number generation.

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.util.Random

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val RANDOM = new Random()

def futureRec(num: Int, f: Future[List[Integer]]): Future[List[Integer]] = {
  if(num == 0) {
    f
  } else {
    f.flatMap(l => {
      futureRec(num - 1, Future.successful(RANDOM.nextInt() :: l))
    })
  }
}

val futureResult = futureRec(5, Future.successful(Nil))

Await.result(futureResult, 5 minutes)
```

So I would do, what you want something like this:

```
def getData(url: String, userID: String):Future[List[PostMD]] = {
  def inner(url: String, f: Future[List[PostMD]]): Future[List[PostMD]] = {

      val chunk: Future[JsValue]  = ???
      chunk.flatMap(ch => {
        val postMd = (ch \ "data").\\("data").map(_.as[PostMD]).toList
        val relatedPostMd = postMd.filter(_.fromID == userID)
        val next: String = (ch.\("paging").\("next")).as[String]
        if (next != null)
           inner(next, f.map(l => l ++ relatedPostMd))
        else
           f.map(l => l ++ relatedPostMd)
      })
  }

  inner(url, Future.successful(Nil))
}
```